# Successive NSURLConnection Requests Fail Authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, nsurlconnection

This seems to be an iOS8 only issue.

I have an app that uses the NSURLConnection delegate. Everything works exactly as it should, except in iOS8 when multiple connections are created and ran successively, an arbitrary number of connections fail to authenticate.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0)
    {
        KeychainItemWrapper *itemWrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[itemWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)] password:[itemWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)] persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        _authenticationChallenged = YES;
    }


    else
    {
        [self cancel];
        KeychainItemWrapper *itemWrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];
        if ([[itemWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Log In" message:@"To use this app, please log in" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Log In", nil];
            [alertView setTag:2];
            [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
            [alertView show];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Credentials" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Log In", nil];
            [alertView setTag:2];
            [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }
}
```

In above code is where the issue lies. The else statement is getting called, even though the credentials are correct and work correctly on every other request. This only happens when I create multiple (separate) NSURLConnections at the same time and run them.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: what do the response headers say for the failed requests?

Comment: The failed requests never return any responses. The problem is that the "if" statement that checks the "previousFailureCount" property fails and it requires authentication again, even though the credentials are stored in the keychain and should be used. Individually the requests all succeed, but when sending multiple requests at once, the "if" statement fails.